Why i got this error when using input in React Hook Form / Shadcn form
I want to make a form to display and update details of a team after fetching data from the api, there is a field metadata, which is a returned as object, when I display try to display it in input element, it shows an error as shown below:

How should I solve this issue? I guess it's because input element cannot be used to hold an object value?
Here is where the error emerge:
    <FormField
      control={form.control}
      name="metadata"
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormItem>
          <FormLabel>Metadata</FormLabel>
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              {...field}
              value={JSON.stringify(teamInfo?.metadata)} //to be confirmed
              disabled={!editMode}
            />
          </FormControl>
          <FormMessage />
        </FormItem>
      )}
    />;

This is the schema of metadata field defined with zod
    metadata: z
      .string()
      .regex(
        /^(\w+:\w+,)*(\w+:\w+)$/,
        'Invalid format, please use key1:value1,key2:value2 format',
      )
      .optional()
      .transform((val) => {
        const metadata: Record<string, string> = {};
        if (val) {
          const pairs = val.split(',');
          for (const pair of pairs) {
            const [key, value] = pair.split(':');
            metadata[key] = value;
          }
        }

        return metadata;
      }),

I have tried overwriting the value property of input element, then the error is gone
    <Input
      {...field}
      value={JSON.stringify(teamInfo?.metadata)} //to be confirmed
      disabled={!editMode}
    />;


Where is the Input field coming from?

The input field metadata is the data retrieved from api, which is an object, but seems Input component does not accept object as value property.

I want to know is there any common practice in designing api, in this scenario, i need to display object type data in a input component. Should i convert the object into string for display? And should i redesign the api to accept property values as string and then parse the string into an object? Cause when i update the metadata field via the input component, there is string sent to the api.

The issue you are experiencing I believe is coming from the transformation, even though we expect the JSON.stringify() to return a string, it is giving us the type of the metadata that comes from the transform function. I think to handle this you will have to deal with converting it into a string yourself.
value = {Object.entries(teamInfo?.metadata ||
 {}).map([key,value] => `${key}:${value}`).join(',')}

The above should do the trick(I hope), but not so sure if its all syntactically valid.

This can solve the error, but setting the value property  will somehow make the input field not editable.

Is there a reason you are using this specifically as the value? it does seem quite abnormal to have a long mapped Record as the value of an input var

I have a form for displaying the metadata retrieved from api, and also allow users to edit the metadata, so I used input component, but seems input component does not accept object type as its value property.

Instead of using a form like this I would create a larger component with an input for each property instead of all of them in one place. It would be simpler for the user and get around your using the object as value.
